# Unable to get Polyline from route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to animate a polyline on top of hidden Route (with `strokeWeight: 0`) and animate it on this example but not sure why I am not able to grab the correct points on `.interpolate()` method.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&libraries=geometry"></script>

var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas').get(0), myOptions);
  //Starting Direction Services

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });

  directionsService.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.999999),
    waypoints: [{
      stopover: false,
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318)
    }],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      // directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWeight: 0
      });
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


      var line = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < polyline.length; i++) {
        var steps = polyline[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }
      var step = 0;
      var numSteps = 250;
      var timePerStep = 5;
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        step += 1;
        if (step > numSteps) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(line, step / numSteps);
          line.setPath([polyline, are_we_there_yet]);
        }
      }, timePerStep);
      line.setMap(map);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: When you're loading in the Maps API, are you including the geometry library?  i.e. like outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries), `&libraries=geometry`

Comment: Hi duncan , yes I already added the library but as you know it is propmting to have the key as well, and that;;s why I didnt out the whole code here

Comment: I just updated the code with referencing to the library

Answer (score 1):

The `interpolate` function takes these three parameters, according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical):

- from: LatLng,
- to: LatLng,
- fraction: number

You're passing it the following two parameters:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(line, step / numSteps)
```

And instead of passing the whole `line`, you should do something like:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(latLng1, latLng2, step / numSteps)
```

... where latLng1 and latLng2 would be the endpoints of your line I guess.

You're also doing this... you create a Polyline, `polyline`.  Then you get a `line`.  But you then try and loop over `polyline.length`:

```
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 0
  });

  var line = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < polyline.length; i++) {
```

I think that last line (and other references inside the nested loops) should refer to the `line` not the `polyline`, i.e.

`for (i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {`

Comment: Thanks again , I updated the code and  I am getting this error now `Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function`

Comment: Ok I totally lost now

Comment: on changing the polyline to line in the for loop I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'steps' of undefined`

Comment: You might want to update your question with your new version of the code.